# XSLT: getting length of start tag

Tags: xslt, xpath, tags, string-length

How do you get the length of an xslt tag at run time?

My code:

```
<Footer xtt:startTag="COUNT" xtt:align="left" xtt:separator="|">
            <Count xtt:align="right" xtt:fixedLength="5"><xsl:value-of select="ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Header/ws:Worker_Count"/></Count>
</Footer>
```

What I want to do is this:

```
<Footer xtt:startTag="COUNT" xtt:align="left" xtt:separator="|">
            <Count xtt:align="right" xtt:fixedLength="10 - string-length( X )"><xsl:value-of select="ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Header/ws:Worker_Count"/></Count>
</Footer>
```

So I want to include the length of the start tag "COUNT" in place of X. I don't want to hardcode the value 5. How do I refer to the start tag in place of "X"?

Comment: Eh? The length of the Count start tag is not 5, it is 45 (everything from the "<" to the ">" inclusive). Did you mean the length of the element name?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use the XPath functions `name()` and `local-name()` to determine the name of a node, then `string-length()` to get the length.

However, referring to the current context node of the result tree is not a standard XSLT feature, so there is no way to refer to the `<Count/>` element of your result tree if you create the element like this.

I know of two possibilities to workaround this limitation:

- If you use XSLT 2.0 or newer, or if you use an XSLT processor that implements this feature on top of XSLT 1.0, you can store the relevant part of the result tree in a variable and then process the result tree fragment as input document (XSLT 1.0 itself doesn't support / allow this).
- You can store the name "Count" in a variable. Then you could use `<xsl:element/>` to create the element in the result tree, referring to the variable for the element name as well as for determining the string length.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in one step:

```
<Footer xtt:startTag="COUNT" xtt:align="left" xtt:separator="|">
            <Count xtt:align="right" xtt:fixedLength="{10 - string-length(ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Header/ws:Worker_Count)}"><xsl:value-of select="ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Header/ws:Worker_Count"/></Count>
</Footer>
```

Or to shorten the code and make sure you only have to edit one expression in case of a change use a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select="ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Header/ws:Worker_Count"/>

<Footer xtt:startTag="COUNT" xtt:align="left" xtt:separator="|">
            <Count xtt:align="right" xtt:fixedLength="{10 - string-length($count)}"><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></Count>
</Footer>
```